# Duda Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, depuración

Necesito saber como hacer para que una macro no me tire el error 1004 y me envíe a depurar sino que se "lo salte" si lo encuentra y continúe con la línea siguiente.
Concretamente creé una macro así:

```
Range("D9").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D9:D10")
Range("D10").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D10:D11")
Range("D11").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D11:D12")
Range("D12").Select
```

Cuando hay una celda que sigue que está combinada me tira el error. Yo quiero que cuando sea así "salte" a la siguiente línea de código.

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner al inicio de la macro la instrucción `On Error Resume Next`, aunque si hay otros errores se los saltará

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Si explicas lo que estás intentando hacer, seguramente se te pueda ayudar mucho mejor. Tu código ahora no tiene mucho sentido, porque por lo que se ve, estás arrastrando la fórmula de D9 a D12, pero lo haces paso a paso. Lo podrías hacer de golpe.

Answer (score 2):

No sé si te puede servir, porque tu pregunta le faltan detalles, pero a ver si esto te sirve.

He simulado datos en Excel, intercalando alguna celda combinada (las amarillas). Tengo una fórmula en D9, que quiero arrastrar hacia abajo, ignorando las celdas combinadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que lo hago con el siguiente código:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim RangoFinal As Range


For Each rng In Range("D9:D15")
    If rng.MergeArea.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If RangoFinal Is Nothing Then
            Set RangoFinal = rng
        Else
            Set RangoFinal = Union(RangoFinal, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next rng

Range("D9").Copy

RangoFinal.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


Set RangoFinal = Nothing
```

El código chequea cada celda en el rango D9:16, y comprueba primero si está combinada. Si no lo está, entonces va creando un `RangoFinal`con todas las celdas individuales.

Después pegamos la fórmula en esas celdas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Bien puso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/144817/roger-torn%c3%a9
Para ignorar cualquier error y continuar la ejecucuión de código, en VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), En cualquier punto activas:

```
On error Resume Next
...
... tu código sin interupciones por errores
...
On error Goto 0
```

Para retornar al tratamiento normal de errores, pones el segundo On error ... como el ejemplo.
Prueba con:

```
On error Resume Next
Range("D9").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D9:D10")
Range("D10").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D10:D11")
Range("D11").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D11:D12")
Range("D12").Select
On Error Goto 0
```

Espero que esto te sirva.